# How to find features that intersect when drawing lines with drawinteraction in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

I am using openlayers version 6.5.0.

I draw a line with drawinteraction.

This line may intersect other lines.

When intersected, can I know the feature information of the intersection and the intersected line?

When drawing is finished, the drawend event is fired.

At this time, the intersection point should be added to the line I drew.

How do I add an intersection point to the line I drew?

The intersection point is not a feature, it should be added as the coordinates of the geometry of the line I drew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use turf.js to find the intersection points

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      #map {
        position: relative;
      }
      #form {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6.3.0/turf.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map">
    <form id="form">
      <label>Geometry type &nbsp;</label>
      <select id="type">
        <option value="Point">Point</option>
        <option value="LineString" selected>LineString</option>
        <option value="Polygon">Polygon</option>
        <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
        <option value="None">None</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-11000000, 4600000],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });

      var typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
      var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

      var drawend = function (event) {
        var geometry = event.feature.getGeometry();
        var type = geometry.getType();
        if (type === "LineString" || type === "Polygon") {
          var geojson1 = format.writeFeaturesObject([event.feature]);
          var extent = geometry.getExtent();
          source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(extent, function (feature) {
            var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
            var type = geometry.getType();
            if (type === "LineString" || type === "Polygon") {
              var geojson2 = format.writeFeaturesObject([feature]);
              var intersects = turf.lineIntersect(geojson1, geojson2);
              var points = format.readFeatures(intersects);
              source.addFeatures(points);
            }
          });
        }
      };

      var draw; // global so we can remove it later
      function addInteraction() {
        var value = typeSelect.value;
        if (value !== 'None') {
          draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: source,
            type: typeSelect.value
          });
          draw.on('drawend', drawend);
          map.addInteraction(draw);
        }
      }


      /**
       * Handle change event.
       */
      typeSelect.onchange = function() {
        map.removeInteraction(draw);
        addInteraction();
      };

      addInteraction();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to insert new vertices into the drawn linestring you would need to run that process for each segment of the linestring to determine where to insert the new vertices.

Note that intersection points will differ depending on the projection used - if the drawn lines in the example were transformed to EPSG:4326 before determining the intersection points the result would look different.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem I had been worried about for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ol-ext ol/interaction/splitter that acts as a split feature agent while editing vector linestring.
See example: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.splitter.html